# How can I save dataset to different parts of the orc files

Tags: java, apache-spark, amazon-s3

I am trying to get data from ms server and save it to orc files in the s3. 
So to do this, I wrote

```
    Dataset<Row> fullDataset =  sparkSession.sqlContext()
            .read()
            .jdbc("jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://ip:port", sqlTableName, 
    getSqlConnectionProperties());
    fullDataset.write().mode(SaveMode.Overwrite).format("orc").save("s3://");
```

But this code saves dataset to one orc file(it doesn't matter how many line has table).
How can I save dataset to the different parts of the orc files? So, I assume that it should be part0.orc, part1.orc, part[n].orc files in the bucket after executing save method.

Comment: fullDataset.repartition(n) doesn't work?

Comment: yep, repartition() should help. what is your desired partition coming from?

Comment: Yes, thanks. repartition() helped but as I understood it didn't bring necessary results. I wanted to make faster transferring data from my ms server to s3 and then to aurora database, but transferring without repartition() was faster than with it.. Also there was not enough memory in heap when I was trying to transfer 30 million rows for example. I didn't change default spark configurations and I can not figure out how memory problem is possible..